# SoftKeyboard not appearing in IOS for TLF Text Fields

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, flash-cs6, tlf

I am using Air 14.0.In Flash Professional CS6.I checked this on iPad.My app contains Login page for that  i used TLF text fields  to username and password fields for some reasons but soft keyboard not appearing.

Comment: Why would it appear? TLF is not made for that. That's why StageText has been added to the API.

Comment: @BotMaster is correct. TLF is not meant for use on mobile devices and frequently does not work correctly. You need to use a `StageText` based input. You should also avoid using TLF for read-only text fields as it is much more difficult to render and can cause frame drops.